# What use is END OF MEMBER In IBM Assembly

Tags: assembly, zos

I am parsing some IBM Assembly Language which also happens to be a BMS map.

The code looks like this:

```
         DFHMSD TYPE=FINAL
         END
END OF MEMBER
```

The `END OF MEMBER` statement is not causing any syntax errors on the mainframe.

Why is it syntactically correct?

What functionality does the `END OF MEMBER` line provide?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.asma100/asmp102194.htm

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Good pointer to doc, but the BMS map is neither a copybook nor a macro so the "END OF MEMBER" might just be left over code from someone copying from a copybook or a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HLASM Reference states:

> If the END statement is not the last statement in the input stream, and the BATCH option has been
>   specified, the assembler initiates assembly of a new source module when the current assembly is
>   completed.

So unless `BATCH` is specified as an asssembler-option processing should stop once the `END`-statement is reached.

You should also be able to see that in your assembly-listing: the printed source-listing should stop at `END`-Statement, `END OF MEBER` should not appear there.

So `END OF MEMBER` seems to have no use but should do no harm either...

Answer (score 3):

I attempted to assemble what you provided in the question and here is what I discovered.

My sample source code is:

**EOS Source**

```
EOS      CSECT         
         SR    15,15   
         BR    14      
         END   EOS     
END OF MEMBER
```

When assembling the source the assemble step completes with a return code 8.  However, it appears to have processed the source up to the **END   EOS** statement.  It then begins to process the following text as a different module.

**Assembly Output Listing**

```
  Active Usings: None                                               
  Loc  Object Code    Addr1 Addr2  Stmt   Source Statement          
                                  1 *                           
000000                00000 00004     2 EOS      CSECT              
000000 1BFF                           3          SR    15,15        
000002 07FE                           4          BR    14           
000000                                5          END   EOS          

                                  Diagnostic Cross Reference and Assembler Summary

     No Statements Flagged in this Assembly                                     
HIGH LEVEL ASSEMBLER, 5696-234, RELEASE 6.0, PTF UI50739
```

Interestingly, I get a set of errors independent of the first CSECT in the same Assembly step that resulted in the return code of 8.  Note the line number of the `END OF MEMBER` is 1.  Those errors are:

**Errors for statements post END**

```
   Active Usings: None                                               
   Loc  Object Code    Addr1 Addr2  Stmt   Source Statement          
                                       1 END OF MEMBER               
 ** ASMA057E Undefined operation code - OF                           
 ** ASMA435I Record 6 in USER1.TEST.CNTL(EOS) on volume: T70502      
 ** ASMA140W END record missing                                      
 ** ASMA435I Record 6 in USER1.TEST.CNTL(EOS) on volume: T70502
```

In this case, there is no issue in that a CSECT was assembled and generated and you could link the module but clearly this is a problem for subsequent steps.

The only reference to the statement `END OF MEMBER` in the HLASM docs is that it is part of the [HLASM exit processing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.asma100/asmp102194.htm).

> The END OF MEMBER call simplifies stack management required in coding a LIBRARY exit which contains READs and FINDs. The exit might use the information provided by this call in the handling of nested FINDs where there is typically a corresponding resume FIND (options=2) for every nested FIND (options=3). For an example of how you can use END OF MEMBER calls to perform stack management, see the code example Use End of Member calls to perform stack management in TERM exit—`TRMEXIT`.

It is not a valid syntax for assembly source code.